# Can exclamation mark/bang symbol be abbreviated?

Tags: vim

While in command mode I'd like to have shell commands output in color. As an example, I'd like `!ls` to be abbreviated as `!ls --color`.

I've tried

```
:cnoreabbrev !ls !ls --color
```

but vim complains of an invalid argument. Escaping the bang doesn't help.

I can't just abbreviate ls because it has it's own meaning in command mode that I use. Is there a workaround to abbreviate commands like `!COMMAND`?

Comment: Vim help says: "*If you want an interactive shell to be used (to use aliases) set `shellcmdflag` to `-ic`.*"

Comment: @melpomene He is using vim abbreviations, not shell aliases.

Comment: @JakeD Yes, but the ultimate goal is to automatically turn `ls` into `ls --color`, which can be (and usually is) done with shell aliases.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, however, then the interface becomes horribly inefficient IMHO because Vim gets suspended if you are running it in a terminal every time you run an external command (not so much of a problem with MacVim or GVim IIRC.

Comment: @JakeD What do you mean, inefficient?

Comment: @melpomene You run a command (like `ls`), then must type `fg<cr><cr>` to return to Vim. Vim is suspended and the shell takes over. I suppose you could make a shell alias like `f=fg` to save one character, but still not very good IMO.

Comment: Why would vim get suspended?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181373/discussion-between-jaked-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that I've found to this is to make my own command in Vim. The following should work for your case although it will require you to exchange having to type the `!` for typing a capital letter at the beginning:

```
:command Ls !ls --color
```

Now you can run the following:

```
:Ls
```

Of course, you can add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
command! Ls !ls --color
```